# How to resolve error 201 in indexing of loops in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops

I am encountring error in loops to iterate from index i to i+24 here following is my code:

```py
# Function to calculate return Position is column in dataframe named data_df
def Return(Position):
    prev_signal = Position.shift(1)
    for i in range(len(Position)):
        if(i > 200):

            if Position[i] == 1 and prev_signal[i] == 0:
                for j in range(i, min(i + 24, len(data_df))):
                    data_df.loc[j, 'return'] = (
                        1-((p+(data_df.loc[j, 'Cumulative P&L']+data_df.loc[j, 'Close']))/p))*100
            elif Position[i] == -1 and prev_signal[i] == 0:
                for j in range(i, min(i + 24, len(data_df))):
                    data_df.loc[j, 'return'] = (
                        1-((p+(data_df.loc[j, 'Cumulative P&L']-data_df.loc[j, 'Close']))/p))*100
            else:
                data_df.loc[i, 'return'] = (
                    1-((p+data_df.loc[i, 'Cumulative P&L'])/p))*100
```

`p` is defined in main code 
I have tried different ways of indexing still I have this error:

```py
#row = self.index.get_loc(index)
#  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-#packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 581, in get_loc
#    raise KeyError(key)
#KeyError: 201
```

I have used Return function to take column Position as an input
then used a loop to iterate in Position column.
I wanted to use another loop to iterate form index[i] to [i+24] when given conditions are true but there is error in indexing which I am not able to figure out.